# Youtube Data API等の利用について

Tags: youtube-data-api, youtube

Youtube Data API等の利用について質問がございます。

1. 現在、クォータ数の上限は10,000ですが、その上限を解放する場合、どれくらいの費用がかかるのでしょうか？
2. Youtube Data APIを利用して、Youtube動画のサムネイル画像のURLを取得するために、クォータコストが"1＋API呼び出し時に使用するパラメーターの数×2クォータ"かかるのは、公式のマニュアルから分かったのですが、取得したURLからサムネイル画像を表示するために、クォータコストはかかるものなのでしょうか？　　
   もしコストがかからなければ、URLさえ画面上に表示しておけば、クォータコストをかけずにサムネイル画像を表示できると思ったのですが、その考えは正しいでしょうか？
3. ２が実現したとして、自分がGoogle Playにあげたアプリ内でそちらを行った場合、作成したアプリがGoogle Playからリジェクトされる可能性はあるのでしょうか？

以上です。
詳しい方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: youtubeapiのプログラムに関する問題ではなくて、仕様や制限の問題ようですのでGoogleに問い合わせたほうが良い内容かと思います。

Comment: [Youtubeヘルプ](https://support.google.com/)を見たところ、
Youtube Data APIに関する質問の入り口はコミュニティかと思いましたので、
そちらで質問しました。

そうしたら、Stack Overflowで質問したほうが回答が得られやすいと返ってきました。→
[Youtube Data API等の利用について](https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/71819189?hl=ja)

問い合わせの窓口がよくわからなくなってしまったのですが、
こちらの質問はどちらで問い合わせればよいのでしょうか？

何かご存知であれば、ご教示いただけるとさいわいです。

Comment: こちらでも質問自体はできますが、ドキュメントに書かれていることや個人の体験より詳しい話はしづらいため、仕様自体について詳しく知りたい場合は Google のエンジニアも見ている英語版の Stack Overflow を使うやり方があります（[参考](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support)）。YouTube ヘルプコミュニティの方は英語版 Stack Overflow と日本語版スタック・オーバーフローを混同なさっているようです。

Comment: 日本語のまま質問を続けるにしろ英語に移るにしろ、今のままだとご質問の中に疑問点が複数含まれてしまっていて回答しづらいので、ひとつの投稿にひとつの疑問となるように [edit] していただけると嬉しいです :-)　参考: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions の「より焦点を絞る必要がある」

Comment: ご連絡が遅くなってしまい申し訳ございません。こちらの件ですが、Youtubeの利用規約ページに、それらしき記述がのっておりましたので、そちらを参考に今後どうするか検討したいと思います。

参考：https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms&hl=ja&gl=JP

また、ご教示いただいたことも今後の参考にさせていただければと思います。
この度は、誠にありがとうございました。